# exported Libraries handling in exported jars java

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have have a java project in eclipse that uses a bunch of jars.I want to export the class as a runnable jar.When i export the project with jar libraries extracted in the jar it gives me an error when running the jar.
 (UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main")

However when i exract the libraries as a subfolder besides the runnable jar it works fine.

How can i make the project work the the libraries used extracted in the jar and not in a subfolder?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has an option to package required library's into the generated JAR. If that is selection that should fix your problem.

[Correct option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWv8y.png)

Comment: This options make the generated jar very slow to execute since the number of jars is a bit large!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're having trouble to export your program as a `Jar` file including the dependencies libraries.

So, the solution is like this:

When you export your project as a 'Runnable jar' (**Right mouse on project -> Export -> Runnable jar**) you have the option to package all dependencies into the generated jar. It also has two other ways (see screenshot) to export your libraries, be aware of the licences when deciding which packaging method you will use.

[image]

**launch configuration** dropdown is populated with classes containing a `public static void main(String[] args)` method. The selected class is started when you run the jar.

Exporting as a runnable jar uses the dependencies on your build path (**Right mouse on project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path...**). When you export as a 'regular' (non-runnable) jar you can select any file in your project. 
If you have the libraries in your project folder you can include them but external dependencies, for example maven, cannot be included.

Also, there another solution using `Gradle`, which is much easier and robust, which you can manage all your dependencies so easyly and do so much more.
You can read more [here](https://www.mkyong.com/gradle/gradle-create-a-jar-file-with-dependencies/).

Comment: Hello. I know how to export project as runnable jar.My problem is that when i choose extract required jars it crashes , when i use the copy into subfolder it works fine.I dont want to use the package into jar because it makes the executable very slow since the number of libraries is a bit large.